# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '' in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

(This is my items.py)

```
import scrapy
class FreelanceItem(scrapy.Item):
url = scrapy.Field()
url = scrapy.Field()
```

When I started another python and imported Package

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item , Field
from freelance.items import FreelanceItem
```

I get this : 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'freelance'

How should I do ?

thanks.

Comment: *"This is my items.py"*: If your file is named `items.py`, you have import it with `from items import FreelanceItem`

Answer (score 1):

Youre accessing it the wrong way..

Lets say you are in a directory called PythonTest, where you also have your main.py file.

Steps:

1. Create a folder named "freelance" in this PythonTest Directory
2. add an empty file in this directory (freelance dir) named  : "_ *init* _.py" (this tells python it is a package)
3. add your items.py file aswell in this directory

Now go to your 'main.py' and add the line:

```
from freelance.items import FreeLanceItem
```

Also make sure to have correct indenting in your code.(see below)

```
import scrapy
class FreeLanceItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
```

running the code should not produce an error anymore.

Let me know if this helped!